# Stop GoogleAnalytics from logging every activity

Tags: android

I'm using the `global_tracker.xml` way to log some of the screens but I'm also using the `Tracker.setScreenName()` way for custom stuff.

My question is: I have an activity tracked with `Tracker.setScreenName()` but it seems that GA also tracks the `Activity` automatically, and it logs the entire path of the class even if I haven't set it in the `global_tracker.xml` file.

Is there a way to stop GA automatically tracking a specific `Activity` ?